# How can I set maximum time in jquery time picker as 12:00 am

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set maximum time as 12:00am in **[jQuery time picker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)**, but it is not working. I am using the following codes:

```
$('#time1').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
        interval: 15,
        minTime: '10',
        maxTime: '12:00am',
        defaultTime: '10',
        startTime: '10:00',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    })
```

However it is accepting `11:59pm`. So how can I set maximum time to 12:00 am?

Comment: From google "By convention, 12 AM denotes midnight and 12 PM denotes noon" so I think it should accept 11:59 PM. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: no poonam, it will not work....And you are right raghav710....it is not accepting, so any way to achieve it.

Comment: which `timepicker` plugin are you using?

Comment: http://timepicker.co/

Comment: **Funny trick:** set it as `12:01` to accept  `12:00`

Comment: Hi Pedram, I have tried that!. It's not working. Actually after 11:59, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This `timepicker` does not account for change in day. So, according to this `timepicker`, the minimum possible time is `00:00` or `12:00am` and the maximum possible time is `23:59` or `11:59pm`.

In your case, you have given `minTime` as `10:00am` and `maxTime` as `12:00am`. If you are not considering the possibility of a change in day in between `minTime` and `maxTime`, your `minTime` is greater than the `maxTime`, which is the reason for failure.

This `timepicker` will work as long as the `minTime` is less than the `maxTime`.